# Closeness of two ARMA models

Tags: time-series, arima

Given two ARMA models, how close will their predictions be? Specializing to the case of ARMA(1,1), if a time series follows an ARMA process

```
y(t) = a*y(t-1) + b*e(t-1) + e(t)
e(t) = N(0,1)
```

what will be the out-of-sample RMSE if I try to predict it with coefficients a' and b' instead of the true coefficients a and b? If I used the true coefficients the out-of-sample RMSE would be 1. I can simulate the answer but wonder if there is an analytical solution.

Comment: I think this is a little too general, so an analytical solution would not be transparent enough to be particularly insightful.